proguard: how to keep all implementation class names except one
proguard: how to keep all implementation class names except one? e.g.
public interface Foo {
   ...
}

public class MyFoo implements Foo {
   ...
}

public class MyFooA extends MyFoo {
   ...
}

public class MyFooB extends MyFoo {
   ...
}

Rules: Keep class names of all the implementations except one MyFoo.
Tried:
-keep class !mypackage.MyFoo, * implements mypackage.Foo

or
-keep class * implements mypackage.Foo, !mypackage.MyFoo

Neither worked. How does the multiple class specifications separated by comma work? It is AND/OR relation?
